# How to remove whitespace in horizontally scrolling text on mouseleave?

Tags: html, jquery, css, overflow

I have this code that when the mouse leaves the span `.ellipsis` class is added and the text returns to the beginning, that's fine. The problem with this is that the `.ellipsis` class when added leaves a white space that I don't want.

[image]

I'm looking for the `.ellipsis` class to be added after the text animation ends.
This is the result (or something similar) is what I need.

[image]

```js
// for stuff that scrolls left on hover
$(".text").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ellipsis");
    var maxscroll = $(this).width();
    var speed = maxscroll * 15;
    $(this).animate({
        scrollLeft: maxscroll
    }, speed, "linear");
});

$(".text").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
    }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 320px;
  background: silver;
}
.text {
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="text ellipsis">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
      of the printing</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text ellipsis">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</span>
</div>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify a callback for `.animate()`:

```js
$(this).animate(/* ... */, function() {
  $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
});
```

Try it:

```js
// for stuff that scrolls left on hover
$(".text").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ellipsis");
    var maxscroll = $(this).width();
    var speed = maxscroll * 15;
    $(this).animate({
        scrollLeft: maxscroll
    }, speed, "linear");
});

$(".text").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({
      scrollLeft: 0
    }, "slow",
    function() {
       $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 320px;
  background: silver;
}
.text {
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="text ellipsis">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
      of the printing</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text ellipsis">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</span>
</div>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```